# Is there a way to reference another local project directory in Maven without using a repository?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, repository

Say I have the following layout on my computer

```
root-directory/
    projectA/
        moduleA1
        moduleA2
        moduleA3
        pom.xml <----------\
    projectB/              |
        moduleB1           | make B's pom.xml reference ../projectA/pom.xml ?
        moduleB2           |
        moduleB3           |
        pom.xml -----------/
```

projectB depends on/references projectA through our company's central (but local) Maven repository.

I need some room to experiment with the interfaces in projectA that projectB depend on, without breaking every other team member's build by committing to our SVN repository - in fact, I want to avoid committing anything at all, including branches, until I have found a good solution the problem that I am actually trying to solve.

It's by chance that projectA and projectB's directories are located in the same directory.

It's only mean to be temporary while I work out some kinks, but I need to keep everything local on my computer.

Comment: Have you got a <localRepository> specified in your settings.xml? You don't need to commit anything to build to your local repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can build your project B(mvn install). This puts the build B into your local repository. Now you can referenc it localy from project A.

Comment: And as to how to reference it locally? Change the pom file's artifact reference? I'm a total newbie to Maven.

Comment: after you build your project B, you can use the project information(groupId, artifactID, version) of B as a normal dependency in A